# How to remove left margin from every nth element with css

Tags: html, css

Here's  a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5b6xyjw/

```
.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}

.col:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.c1-4 {
  width: 23.8%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

<div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
</div>
```

Every time it starts in a new line I want it without the left margin.

I've triend with :nth-child(5n) but that only removes it for one row.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child(4n + 1)` and that will be each 4th element + 1 which will be first element on each line.

```css
.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
}
.c1-4 {
  width: 23.8%;
  height: 90px;
}
.col:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
  <div class="col c1-4"></div>
</div>
```